# require() fails in a Firefox/Tor Browser extension (extension signing?)

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, require

I am developing an extension for Firefox and Tor Browser (as well as Chrome).

I added `chromium/background-scripts/urlbarprovidertoronion.js`, but when I try to load it, I get an error. Apparently it is related with extension signing, because other JS files in the same folder load fine. Please help!!!

I have

```
UrlbarProviderTorOnion = require('./urlbarprovidertoronion').UrlbarProviderTorOnion
```

in `chromium/background-scripts/background.js`.

`Error: module: ./urlbarprovidertoronion not found.`

Also, when I type, `require('./urlbarprovidertoronion').UrlbarProviderTorOnion` in console, it works fine. It is some mystery related with extension signing. Explain me how to get around of this in Tor (apparently the same as in Firefox).

Note that I did add my script to `manifest.json`.

Comment: Does it work in Chrome extension?

Comment: No, in Chrome I also have
`Uncaught Error: module: ./urlbarprovidertoronion not found.
    at require (bootstrap.js:7)
    at background.js:15
    at background.js:960`

Comment: Try using a full path as it's seen from the root of the extension (root = manifest.json directory).

Comment: @wOxxOm But other JS files do load successfully (the trouble is specific to `urlbarprovidertoronion.js`) from the same `background.js`.

Comment: Well, without a real [MCVE](/help/mcve) all we can do is guess and that's nonproductive.